# Form not showing in Django app

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, cookiecutter-django

I picked up a very very simple django challenge, but am having a problem with inputing details and submitting it into Database. My forms are not even showing talkless of inputing details, and I don’t know what am doing wrong.

**models.py**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.template import RequestContext
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .models import Users
from .forms import UserForm

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', {})


def list(request):
    users = Users.objects.order_by('created_at').all()
    context = {'users': users}
    return render(request, 'pages/list.html', context)


def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User(name=request.POST['name'], email=request.POST['email'])
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/list/')

    return render(request, 'pages/list.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from .models import Users
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', max_length=60, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if Users.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email already exists')
        return email
```

**add.html** (Template):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>Add user</h1>
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <form name='form' method="POST" action="/add/">
                {% csrf_token %} {% for field in form %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }} {% if field.errors %}
                    <ul class="errorlist">
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <li>{{ error|escape }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views import defaults as default_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/home.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^list/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/list.html'), name='list'),
    url(r'^add/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/add.html'), name='add'),
    url(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/about.html'), name='about'),

    # Django Admin, use {% url 'admin:index' %}
    url(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls),

    # User management
    url(r'^users/', include('seedstar_django_challenge.users.urls', namespace='users')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    # Your stuff: custom urls includes go here


] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    # This allows the error pages to be debugged during development, just visit
    # these url in browser to see how these error pages look like.
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^400/$', default_views.bad_request, kwargs={'exception': Exception('Bad Request!')}),
        url(r'^403/$', default_views.permission_denied, kwargs={'exception': Exception('Permission Denied')}),
        url(r'^404/$', default_views.page_not_found, kwargs={'exception': Exception('Page not Found')}),
        url(r'^500/$', default_views.server_error),
    ]
    if 'debug_toolbar' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        import debug_toolbar
        urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
        ] + urlpatterns
```

When I check my logs, I get this below:

[image: Error Log]

So when I click Add nothing happens, no form to input not to talk of saving the details in DB. The repo is [here](https://github.com/AfolabiOlaoluwa/seedstar_django_challenge/tree/master/seedstar_django_challenge/task1) if you need to see that well.

Where am I wrong?

Note am using cookiecutter.

Comment: Please show your URLs. Also what view is responsible for rendering add.html?

Comment: @DanielRoseman added.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**URLS**

```
url(r'^add/', views.AddUserView.as_view(), name='add'),
```

**views**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class AddUserView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/add.html"
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):     
        print(request)
        return render(request, 'pages/list.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

None of your URLs actually go to the views you have defined. So POST will never be accepted and the form will never be present in the context. I don't know why you have done that, but you shouldn't.

```
from my_app import views

url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^list/', views.list, name='list'),
url(r'^add/', views.add, name='add'),
```

Comment: But why is signup and signin working if they aint going to views?

Comment: Presumably they are managed by the allauth include. They don't seem to have anything to do with this.